# Why doesn't discriminated union work when I omit/require props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component which renders different elements based on a specific property, called `type`. It could have type definitions like this:

```
interface CommonProps {
  size: 'lg' | 'md' | 'sm';
}

interface SelectInputProps extends CommonProps {
  type: 'select';
  options: readonly Option[];
  selected: string;
}

interface TextInputProps extends CommonProps {
  type: 'text';
  value: string;
};

type InputProps = (SelectInputProps | TextInputProps) & ExtraProps;

function Field(props: InputProps): JSX.Element;
```

Now in my own component, I will access the properties of this component, like so:

```
import { ComponentProps } from 'react';

type FieldProps = ComponentProps<typeof Field>;

function MySpecialField(props: FieldProps) {
  if (props.type === 'select') {
    // this works
    const { options, selected } = props;
  }
  return <Field {...props} />
}
```

This works absolutely fine. It knows in my `if` block that `props` is `SelectInputProps`. However, I made one small change and it appeared to completely break this mode of using the discriminated union.

```
type FieldProps = Omit<ComponentProps<typeof Field>, 'size'>;
```

[In practice, here is what is happening](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCpgE8wk4B5MGYCAOzgF44BvADYoARkgEAuOAGcYUYBwDmAGjgA3FAICuSSTLmKAvhWqV5MJFEzpGAUQAeslAAUcYKfypw4RFABNOArRwKJIcmiCiUMZePv4cgXDCAPy6svIKxgZUNPSMAGLAYr4uEG48HpRedAyS+FJiSCTRcKVsnFKSLG0cANoAuplwAGRw9o4lZQA+FVW5teYO+EqeahraqfoZVAbDow5Qzq5SxlSYmhwY7FwFRQAUYEeSNwLFRwCUM3DAmHD3RwB01UY3BBBHqAkaMHwHz4Ky8aHa8D4rSuUhU-wxRBkO14D1Kxzh3iQME0UC4t0JXgAPODIfwMf8sTADAA+Slefh4tz-FHtf4gFBgW63PhwISiAQqdRaRgGD7cFm-dkcuBU3lcADWSFo3D40u0O31SF1RtZghEYgMVIA9Oq2ZUVRy3m8sg6VTbaRh7Sq3itXV5vr8uVJAbkeKD8AsoTDCUQSWTVfIwJokQzgztrd64P6ifGuGEBAJMtlKNaAFRlzxluAAFQAFsB3AB3aAaqRV605BhwACytGer3xAHVW+lysh0DB-gBhXCQDhIDgwCZSKlAiA-Acsk6UM4Xbq9-uFF4jqAa9J-fGSPsDlen8+KGMOwOX7lA8O8OoNEhPlUIjgyC0rCouUwY8sB7TNDmcaklwVJJimcCZtsJblpWlTVvWjZwP4SBSBwkYdl2jA3seg5lLwTAgMAMBUhOGAznOnCLsuRxrrkG5wFuKj4Cg+DbiWe6XJwh4Dq+HSiWRK6-l8PziaG3Ygp+nrRp8XjWtacAABIWEgdRwDAdaMHiwgQiAhL-oB6ruLiALWVBKwwQm8EcMm8DIZQBhAA)

Why is this happening? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because [the `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) does not *distribute* over [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T`.  The [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4c018818c11b6c82cb2a2c061423fd28d56796ef/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1516) uses `keyof T`, and when `T` is a union, `keyof T` is only those keys that exist in all members of the union (`keyof T` is *contravariant* in `T`, so `keyof (A | B)` is equivalent to `(keyof A) & (keyof B)`).  This is working as intended as per [microsoft/TypeScript#31501](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31501).

Luckily, if you want a distributive version of `Omit`, you can write it yourself using a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type DistributiveOmit<T, K extends PropertyKey> =  
  T extends any ? Omit<T, K> : never;
```

And then you can see the change in behavior:

```
type MyFieldProps = DistributiveOmit<React.ComponentProps<typeof Field>, 'a'>;
/* type MyFieldProps = Omit<{
    type: 'select';
    options: Option[];
} & ExtraProps, "a"> | Omit<{
    type: 'text';
    value: string;
} & ExtraProps, "a"> */
```

which makes your code start working:

```
function MyField(props: MyFieldProps) {
  if (props.type === 'select') {
    const options = props.options;    // okay
  }
  return <input />
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCpgE8wk4B5MGYCAOzgF44BvADYoARkgEAuOAGcYUYBwDmAGjgA3FAICuSSTLmKAvhWqV5MJFEzpGAUQAeslAAUcYKfypw4RFABNOArRwKJIcmiCiUMZePv4cgXDCAPy6svIKxgZUNPSMAGLAYr4uEG48HpRedAyS+FJiSCTRcKVsnFKSLG0cANoAuplwAGRw9o4lZQA+FVW5teYO+EqeahraqfoZVAbDow5Qzq5SxlSYmhwY7FwFRQAUYEeSNwLFRwCUM3DAmHD3RwB01UY3BBBHqAkaMHwHz4Ky8aHa8D4rSuUhU-wxRBkO14D1Kxzh3iQME0UC4t0JXgAPODIfwMf8sTADAA+Slefh4tz-FHtf4gFBgW63PhwISiAQqdRaRgGD7cFm-dkcuBU3lcADWSFo3D40u0O31SF1RtZghEYgMVIA9Oq2ZUVRy3m8sg6VTbaRh7Sq3itXV5vr8uVJAbkeKD8AsoTDCUQSWTVfIwJokQzgztrd64P6ifGuGEBAJMtlKNaAFRlzxluAAFQAFsB3AB3aAaqRV605BhwACytGer3xAHVW+lysh0DB-gBhXCQDhIDgwCZSKlAiA-Acsk6UM4Xbq9-uFF4jqAa9J-fGSPsDlen8+KGMOwOX7lA8O8OoNEhPlUIjgyC0rCouUwY8sB7TNDmcaklwVJJimcCZtsJbvgAIo2aTCCmwCqEgTAgMAMBUjWKgANJwEgDiLr47gTBYdBkdqiq8LWlHURwtHBBwQRJMwhHEaRcBkYqoRIHhUSoWGN7HoOZS8BhejANhbB4QRRFUhOGAznOnCLsuRxrrkG5wFuKj4Cg+DblQ5ZwO+MlFCu5TqcRsJunZcxgt+ULNF46odMwEG9AM2y7GMBwrioABEKBRYq0wuVSbkqkC8xUT5hJGhs6SDCM4WHPi0WxYqZadiYpznJcnCHgOr4BQ5Lwrr+Xw-HVobdiCn6etGnzwoiQHdO4uIAv5pAqta1otBqKC0H6KwwQm8EcMm8DIZQrpdowABqJEsfwPQUfIcBarQJk1n0kg9DWB19H0G2UO+ABa5Q7XwIRwAAjDs0x8MIkgAEyskAA)

```
function MyField(props: MyFieldProps) {
  if (props.type === 'select') {
    // Here's the problem
    const options = props.options;
  }
  return <input />
}
```

Comment: the same can be done for `Required` and other utility types, right?

Comment: Yes, you can distributive across unions yourself with something like `type Distributive<T> = T extends any ? NonDistributive<T> : never`